# Mesh simplification of a grid-like structure

Tags: opengl, 3d, mesh, simplification

I'm working on a 3D building app. The building is done on a 3D grid (like a Rubik's Cube), and each cell of the grid is either a solid cube or a 45 degree slope. To illustrate, here's a picture of a chamfered cube I pulled off of google images:

[image]

Ignore the image to the right, the focus is the one on the left. Currently, in the building phase, I have each face of each cell drawn separately. When it comes to exporting it, though, I'd like to simplify it. So in the above cube, I'd like the up-down-left-right-back-front faces to be composed of a single quad each (two triangles), and the edges would be reduced from two quads to single quads.

What I've been trying to do most recently is the following:

Iterate through the shape layer by layer, from all directions, and for each layer figure out a good simplification (remove overlapping edges to create single polygon, then split polygon to avoid holes, use ear clipping to triangulate).

I'm *clearly* over complicating things (at least I hope I am). If I've got a list of vertices, normals, and indices (currently with lots of duplicate vertices), is there some tidy way to simplify? The limitations are that indices can't be shared between faces (because I need the normals pointing in different directions), but otherwise I don't mind if it's not the fastest or most optimal solution, I'd rather it be easy to implement and maintain.

EDIT: Just to further clarify, I've already performed hidden face removal, that's not an issue. And secondly, it's of utmost importance that there is no degradation in quality, only simplification of the faces themselves (I need to retain the sharp edges).

Comment: you should first focus on removing hidden faces

Comment: Have you [read this paper](http://www.jerrytalton.net/research/Talton04SSMSA.report/Talton04SSMSA.pdf)? It's 10 years old but still very useful. There is also [the OpenMesh framework](http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.0-Documentation/decimater_docu.html) that might help.

Comment: Ratchet- Done with removing hidden faces, I just don't have any shared vertices between faces at the moment. @Roger - The paper looks great! Will be studying it. As for OpenMesh, I'll look into it. I had some success trying Blender's decimation tool, although it  required a fair amount of manual tweaking to get it simplified without it eating up any "important" vertices. A lot of methods simplify too indiscriminately to be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks goes to Roger Rowland for the great tips! If anyone else stumbles upon this question, here's a short summary of what I did:

First thing to tackle: ensure that the mesh you are attempting to simplify is a manifold mesh! This is a requirement for traversing halfedge data structures. One instance where I has issues with this was overlapping quads and triangles; I initially resolved to just leave the quads whole, rather than splitting them into triangles, because it was easier, but that resulted in edges that broke the halfedge mesh.

Once the mesh is manifold, create a halfedge mesh out of the vertices and faces.

With that done, decimate the mesh. I did it via edge collapsing, determining which edges to collapse through *normal deviation* (in my case, if the resulting faces from the collapse had normals not equal to their original values, then the collapse was not performed).

I did this via my own implementation at first, but I started running into frustrating bugs, and thus opted to use OpenMesh instead (it's very easy to get started with).

There's still one issue I have yet to resolve: if there are two cubes diagonally to one another, touching, the result is an edge with four faces connected to it: a complex edge! I suspect it'd be trivial to iterate through the edges checking for the number of faces connected, and then resolving by duplicating the appropriate vertices. But with that said, it's not something I'm going to invest the time in fixing, unless it becomes a critical issue later on.

Answer (score 0):

Google "mesh simplification".  You'll find that this problem is a huge one and is heavily researched.  Take a look at these introductory resources: [link](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/SLIDES/Simplification.pdf) (p.11 starts the good stuff) and [link](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/LectureSlides/08_Simplification.pdf).  CGAL has a good discussion, as well: [link](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_simplification/index.html).

Once familiar with the issues, you'll have some decisions for applying simplification to your problem.  How fast should the simplification be? How important is accuracy?  (Iterative vertex clustering is a quick and dirty approach, but its results can be arbitrarily ugly.)  Can you rely on a 3rd party library? (i.e. CGAL? [GTS](http://gts.sourceforge.net/) doesn't appear active any longer, but there are others) .

Answer (score 0):

I am giving a theoretical answer.

For the figure left, find all 'edge sharing triangles' with same normal (same x,y,z coordinates)(make it unit normal because of uneffect of direction of positive scaling of vectors). Merge them. Then triangulate it with maximum aspect ratio will give a solution you want.

Another easy and possible way for mesh simplification is I am proposing now.
Take the **NORMALS** and divide with magnitude(root of sum of squares of coordinates), gives unit normal vector. And take the adjucent triangles and take **DOT PRODUCT** between them(multiply x,y,z coordinates each and add). It gives the **COSINE** value of angle between these normals or triangles. Take a range(like 0.99-1) and consider the all adjacent triangles in this range with respect to referring triangle and merge them and retriangulate. We definitely can ignore some triangles in weird directions with smaller areas.

There is also another proposal for a more simple mesh reduction like in your left figure or building figures. Define a pre-defined number of faces (here 6+8 = 14) means value of normals, and classify all faces according to the direction close to these(by dot product) and merge and retriangulate.